# c# file or MainPage.xml.cs in Cordova/Phonegap windows project

Tags: c#, windows, cordova, windows-phone-8

I am converting my app from a WP8 project to a windows project.  If you run the command

```
cordova platform add windows
```

Cordova will create a solution with 4 projects, one for Windows 8.1, 1 for Windows 8, one for Windows Phone and the shared project.  From what i can see, these are javascript projects, but i need to run some c# code to start a background service when the app starts.  In a WP8 project you can add this code to the Mainpage.xml.cs file.

Is there no c# code that runs in these types of projects, or can you attach any code to run upon startup?  How do people start background tasks in these apps else?

Answer (score 0):

In [Apache Cordova main page](https://cordova.apache.org/), there is a bunch of links to download Cordova Component for each platform. Choose the one for WP8 GitHub repository, and you will be redirected to

https://github.com/apache/cordova-wp8

Download the repository as a Zip from the right hand side of the page, after unzipping the file, you will happily find that the Cordova library and the project template are written in C#.